# Haskell do notation to bind

Tags: haskell, do-notation

I´am trying to desugar a do statement in Haskell. I have found some examples here on SO but wasn´t able to apply them to my case. 
Only thing I can think of is a heavy nested let statement, which seems quite ugly.

Statement in which do notation should be replaced by bind:

```
do num <- numberNode x
   nt1 <- numberTree t1
   nt2 <- numberTree t2
   return (Node num nt1 nt2)
```

Any input is highly appreciated =)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
numberNode x >>= \num ->
  numberTree t1 >>= \nt1 ->
    numberTree t2 >>= \nt2 ->
      return (Node num nt1 nt2)
```

Note that this is simpler if you use Applicatives:

```
Node <$> numberNode x <*> numberTree t1 <*> numberTree t2
```

Comment: Thank for pushing my head against this wall. Don´t know why, but I just didn´t of this simple solution.

Answer (score 8):

This is an excellent use case for [applicative style](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applicative_functor#Usage). You can replace your entire snippet (after importing `Control.Applicative`) with

```
Node <$> numberNode x <*> numberTree t1 <*> numberTree t2
```

Think of the applicative style (using `<$>` and `<*>`) as "lifting" function application so it works on functors as well. If you mentally ignore `<$>` and `<*>` it looks quite a lot like normal function application!

Applicative style is useful whenever you have a pure function and you want to give it impure arguments (or any functor arguments, really) -- basically when you want to do what you specified in your question!

---

The type signature of `<$>` is

```
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

which means it takes a pure function (in this case `Node`) and a functor value (in this case `numberNode x`) and it creates a new function wrapped "inside" a functor. You can add further arguments to this function with `<*>`, which has the type signature

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

As you can see, this is very similar to `<$>` only it works even when the function is wrapped "inside" a functor.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this, I have no experience with applicatives but the concept looks awesome. It is just this kind of beautifull ways to solve problems I like about Haskell :) As I was asking for bind operator I will accept Gabriels answer, but I will definitely take a deeper look at this concept. Thank you very much for pointing this out to me =)

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add to the posts about Applicative above..

Considering the type of `<$>`:

```
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

it looks just like fmap:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

which is also very much like Control.Monad.liftM:

```
liftM :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
```

I think of this as "I need to lift the data constructor into this type"

On a related note, if you find yourself doing this:

```
action >>= return . f
```

you can instead do this:

```
f `fmap` action
```

The first example is using bind to take the value out of whatever type action is, calling f with it, and then repacking the result. Instead, we can lift f so that it takes the type of action as its argument.

Comment: Thanks for this continuative explanation =)

Comment: `liftM3 :: Monad m => (a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m a3 -> m r` or `liftA3 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c -> d) -> f a -> f b -> f c -> f d` are available by importing `Control.Monad` or `Control.Applicative`, and are more useful than plain `fmap`/`liftM` here. For example, `liftA3 Node (numberNode x) (numberTree t1) (numberTree t2)` would do the trick.

Comment: As it stands, this doesn't actully answer the question. The OP can't use it to solve the problem they have. That's why you need liftM3 or Applicative.