# Haskell: words count from a getLine without the "do" notation

Tags: haskell, getline, notation

How do I write the following function without using the "do" notation?

```
wordsCount =  do 
    putStr "Write a line and press [enter]:\n"
    s <- getLine
    putStr $ show $ length . words $ s
    putChar '\n'
```

Comment: These two questions ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16964732/2211273), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25255260/2211273)) questions also are about desugaring do syntax. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16726740/2211273) also explains nicely how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using [`do`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#do), you can use [`>>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62-) and [`>>=`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62--61-):

```
wordsCount = putStr "Write a line and press [enter]:\n" >> getLine >>= putStr . show . length . words >> putChar '\n'
```

Or making it easier to read:

```
wordsCount = putStr "Write a line and press [enter]:\n" >>
    getLine >>=
    putStr . show . length . words >>
    putChar '\n'
```

A more straight-forward translation would be:

```
wordsCount = putStr "Write a line and press [enter]:\n" >>
    getLine >>=
    \s -> (putStr $ show $ length $ words s) >>
    putChar '\n'
```

Basically the compiler converts such `do`-notation blocks to its monadic equivalent (using only `>>` and `>>=`). `do` is only syntactical sugar such that one does not have to write `>>=` each time and/or mange variables.

**Additional notes:**

- as @ChadGilbert said in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662754/haskell-words-count-from-a-getline-without-the-do-notation/37662972?noredirect=1#comment62804606_37662972), the parenthesis should be wrapped around the function, excluding the `\s ->` such that the `s` can be used later on in the program, for example:

  ```
  -- This is not an equivalent program
  wordsCount = putStr "Write a line and press [enter]:\n" >>
      getLine >>=
      \s -> (putStr $ show $ length $ words s) >>
      putChar '\n' >>
      putStrLn s -- repeat s
  ```
- Instead of using `putStr` and `putChar`, you can use [`putStrLn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn). For example:

  ```
  wordsCount = putStr "Write a line and press [enter]:\n" >>
      getLine >>=
      putStrLn . show . length . words
  ```

Comment: In your more straight-forward translation, shouldn't the parentheses be wrapping simply the `putStr $ show $ length $ words s` statement? Wrapping `(\s -> putStr $ show $ length $ words s)` means that `s` is not usable in subsequent monadic statements

Comment: @ChadGilbert: you mean like the updated answer? Yes indeed. Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: @ChadGilbert: I've updated the answer with an additional note to further explain the isue, many thanks.